# highcharts gradient line (adding a third dimension to a 2d chart)

Tags: highcharts

Do you think I can achieve this in highcharts?
I have dataset with 3 variables: X,Y and Date. I need to plot on a X Y chart the variables X and Y, but also I would like to present the date as gradient on the line. For example, if the series has a green color assigned, the oldest point in the series would be set to a light green and the most recent a dark green.

Thanks.
Leandro